# Meson doesn't link shared library

Tags: c++, templates, ninja, meson-build

My project has following structure:

```
$ find ~/template
template/
template/meson.build
template/src
template/src/template
template/src/template/geometry.cc
template/src/template/geometry.hh
template/src/template/main.cc
template/src/template/meson.build
template/src/meson.build
```

Relevant files:

```
$ cat ~/template/src/template/geometry.hh
#ifndef GEOMETRY_H
#define GEOMETRY_H

template <class T>
class Circle {
    public:
        Circle(T radius);
        T area() const;
        T radius() const;
    private:
        T _radius;
};
#endif
```

```
$ cat ~/template/src/template/geometry.cc
#include <numbers>
#include "geometry.hh"

template <class T>
Circle<T>::Circle(T radius): _radius(radius) {}

template <class T>
T Circle<T>::area() const {
    return std::numbers::pi * _radius * _radius;
}

template <class T>
T Circle<T>::radius() const {
    return _radius;
}

template class Circle<float>;
```

```
$ cat ~/template/src/template/main.cc
int main() {
    Circle<float> fc(3.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

```
$ cat ~/template/src/template/meson.build
geometry = shared_library(
  'geometry',
  sources: ['geometry.cc']
)

executable(
  'app',
  link_with: geometry,
  sources: ['main.cc'],
  include_directories: src
)
```

Attempting building fails with undefined reference to Circle class, which should be there because of explicit template instantiation in .cc file, and shared_library should load automatically, so no explicit include directive required.

```
$ ~/template/build$ ninja
[0/1] Regenerating build files.
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.2
Source dir: /home/afficionado/template
Build dir: /home/afficionado/template/build
Build type: native build
Project name: template
Project version: 0.0.0
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 10.2.0 "c++ (GCC) 10.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ ld.bfd 2.34
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
Build targets in project: 2

Found ninja-1.10.0 at /gnu/store/2qk7mi55czwj92hkdgfrcljwdbb3cx4p-profile/bin/ninja
[1/3] Compiling C++ object 'src/template/9deed4d@@app@exe/main.cc.o'.
FAILED: src/template/9deed4d@@app@exe/main.cc.o
c++ -Isrc/template/9deed4d@@app@exe -Isrc/template -I../src/template -Isrc -I../src -fdiagnostics-color=always -pipe -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -Wall -Winvalid-pch -Wnon-virtual-dtor -std=c++2a -g -MD -MQ 'src/template/9deed4d@@app@exe/main.cc.o' -MF 'src/template/9deed4d@@app@exe/main.cc.o.d' -o 'src/template/9deed4d@@app@exe/main.cc.o' -c ../src/template/main.cc
../src/template/main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
../src/template/main.cc:2:5: error: ‘Circle’ was not declared in this scope
    2 |     Circle<float> fc(3.0f);
      |     ^~~~~~
../src/template/main.cc:2:12: error: expected primary-expression before ‘float’
    2 |     Circle<float> fc(3.0f);
      |            ^~~~~
```

Maybe some specific arguments required to accomplish this, but I'm relatively new to Meson and cannot find any examples in its docs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're forgetting `#include "geometry.hh"` in your main.cc file. That's the reason it can't find the `Circle` class declaration.